# Swagger returning xml format instead of json.I need json format to view

Tags: java, json, rest, swagger

In my project i am using swagger.this working fine for me .i am using swagger version 0.5.0.i need to generate json format of output but swagger produce only xml format.how to reslove this error.i am using spring and rest service.

```
    pom.xml

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>csrfspring</groupId>
        <artifactId>csrfspring</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>



        <properties>
            <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
            <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>

            <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
            <javax.servlet.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
                <scope>provider</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>




            <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>${jstl.version}</version>
            </dependency>



            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version> <!-- Put here the version of your Java EE app, in my case 7.0 -->
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>


    </project>

Spring xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">


    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.examle.anand" />

<bean class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.DocumentationConfig" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/swagger.properties" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>

controller in java
package com.examle.anand;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;

@Controller
@Api(value = "hello", description = "it simple test api") 
@RequestMapping("/hello")

public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(value="/test",method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {

      System.out.println("TEsted i am inside controller");
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

Comment: That is a TON of code. Have you narrowed it down to where the problem is occurring? I'd recommend helping us to help you by [paring down the example code to a minimal but complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: pom.xml what are dependecy i am using .and spring xml how configuration for compenent scan to my java controller.and controller defines which controller i am using.above code very simple example

Answer (score 0):

Just create Java object from your XML by common XML libs and then create JSON by Jackson lib. Look at http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/jackson-create-json.jsp And read swegger specification http://swagger.io/specification/. But of you wanna full JSON support, so use RAML.